# Nginx Substitution Module sub_filter replace content coming from PHP

Tags: nginx, php

I set up a simple sub_filter to replace the head with head and a base href.
This works perfectly fine with .html files but it fails with .php
Anyone an idea how to get this working with php?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer - it was simpler than expected:

```
    location / {
            if ($uri ~* ^/([^.\?/]+)) {
                    set $foldername "$1";
            }
            sub_filter "<head>" "<head><base href=\"${scheme}://${host}/${foldername}/\">";
    }
```